# search using perl one liner within a file

Tags: perl

I have a file that looks like this:

```
dee    123    
bee    555    
dee    56    
cee    29    
dee    30    
cee     13
```

I need the output like this:

```
dee  123,56,30    
bee  555    
cee   29,13
```

How can I perform this task using perl one-liners?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -alnwe '
    push @{$a{$F[0]}}, $F[1]; 
    }{ 
    for (keys %a) { print $_, "  ", join ",",@{$a{$_}} } ;'
```

**Output:**

```
cee  29,13
dee  123,56,30
bee  555
```

**Explanation:**

- `-a` autosplit input line on whitespace
- `-l` handle newlines
- `-n` assume `while(<>)` loop around program
- `@F` array comes from autosplit, `$F[0]` and `$F[1]` are the array elements.
- `%a` is where we store results, first column as keys, second in the value as an array
- `}{` the eskimo operator, with the `-n` switch does the same as an `END` block

In the last section we just print the keys and values.

Comment: @user1598776 You can click the check mark beside the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you most of the way there ('x' is the filename):

```
perl -ane 'm/^([^ ]+) +(\d+)/; if ($name{$1} ne "") { $name{$1} .= ","; }; $name{$1} .= $2; END { foreach (sort(keys(%name))) { print $_ . "    " . $name{$_} . "\n"; } }' x
```

The output for this one-liner:

```
bee    555
cee    29,13
dee    123,56,30
```

Comment: Yeah, I was being very cheap and antique-school.